# React Native unmounted screen renders when Redux state changed

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I'm using React Native with Redux. Currently i'm having two screens that uses same redux state. Two screen are on a stack navigation. There is a use effect call in the 1st screen that trigger when the redux state changed. same kind a use effect call is also in the 2nd screen that trigger when same redux state changed. The problem is when i navigate from screen 1 to screen 2 and changed the state, it triggers both use effects.

This is 1st Screen. I'm navigating to 2nd screen using navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')

```
export default function StartScreen({route, navigation, props}) {
  const {loginStatus,user} = useSelector(state => state.auth);

const initialRender = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect');
    if (!initialRender.current) {
      if (loginStatus === 'success') {
        hideDialog();
        navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{name: 'Dashboard'}],
        });
      } else if(loginStatus === 'failed') {
        alert('invalid QR code!')
        hideDialog();
        dispatch(clearLoginStatus())
      }
    } else {
      initialRender.current = false;
    }
  }, [loginStatus]);

return (
    <Background maxWidth="85%">
      <VectorHeading
        img={require('../assets/startvector.png')}
        marginBottom={50}
      />
      <Header>xxxxxxx</Header>
      <Paragraph>
        The easiest way to start with your amazing application.
      </Paragraph>
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('QRScanner')}>
        Scan QR
      </Button>
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LoginScreen')}>
        Login
      </Button>

      <Loader visible={visible} hideDialog={hideDialog} />
    </Background>
  );

.........
```

This is 2nd Screen

```
export default function LoginScreen({navigation, props}) {
  ....
  const {isLoggedIn, loginStatus,user} = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  

const initialRender = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect');
    if (!initialRender.current) {
      if (loginStatus === 'success') {
        hideDialog();
        forward();
      } else if(loginStatus === 'failed') {
        alert('invalid credentials!')
        hideDialog();
        dispatch(clearLoginStatus())
      }
    } else {
      initialRender.current = false;
    }
  }, [loginStatus]);

.........
```

When "loginStatus" changed it rendering useefect functions in both screens and show both alerts that setted inside useeffect.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another useEffect to clean up when component unmounts,

```
useEffect(() => {
 return () => {
   console.log("cleaned up");
 };
}, []);
```

Comment: It's not working with the useEffect you mentioned. It still triggers the previous page state changes. Any other way to try mchn?